# htaccess rewrite similar leading character but different patterns all going to same substitution

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this set of URI's:

```
RewriteRule ^/?products|Main/abcd_?blue_?small.*$ /scrpts/abcd_blues_small.php      [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?products|Main/abcd_?red_?big.*$ /scrpts/abcd_red.big.php      [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?products|Main/abcd_?green.*$ /scrpts/abcd_green.php      [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?products|Main/abcd_?yellow_?large.*$ /scrpts/abcd_yellow.php      [NC,R,L]
```

After reading many posts and trying many different rules and conditions I'm missing something and not getting the rules to work as needed. I really need some help!

Using these links for testing shows all tests going to the same substitution (/scrpts/abcd_blues_small.php) which is the first ReWrite rule when each should go to the different substitutions:

```
/Products/abcd_blue_small.asp
/Products/abcdbluesmall.html
/Main/abcdbluesmall.php
/Main/abcd_blue_small.asp
/Products/abcdredbig.html
/Products/abcdredbig.html  
/Products/abcd_green.asp
/Products/abcd_green.php  
/Products/abcdyellowlarge.asp
/Products/abcdyellowlarge.php
```

When using the "/Products/abcdyellowlarge.asp" test the rewrite log looks like this -

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2016:16:46:33 --0500] [dart/sid#7fb5728385b8][rid#7fb572a796a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/santa/Sites/www.dartpro.com/] add path info postfix: /Users/santa/Sites/www.dartpro.com/Products -> /Users/santa/Sites/www.dartpro.com/Products/abcdyellowlarge.asp
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2016:16:46:33 --0500] [dart/sid#7fb5728385b8][rid#7fb572a796a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/santa/Sites/www.dartpro.com/] strip per-dir prefix: /Users/santa/Sites/www.dartpro.com/Products/abcdyellowlarge.asp -> Products/abcdyellowlarge.asp
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2016:16:46:33 --0500] [dart/sid#7fb5728385b8][rid#7fb572a796a0/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/santa/Sites/www.dartpro.com/] applying pattern '^/?products|Main/abcd_?blue_?small.*$' to uri 'Products/abcdyellowlarge.asp'
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2016:16:46:33 --0500] [dart/sid#7fb5728385b8][rid#7fb572a796a0/initial] (2) [perdir /Users/santa/Sites/www.dartpro.com/] rewrite 'Products/abcdyellowlarge.asp' -> '/scrpts/abcd_blues_small.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2016:16:46:33 --0500] [dart/sid#7fb5728385b8][rid#7fb572a796a0/initial] (2) [perdir /Users/santa/Sites/www.dartpro.com/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://dart/scrpts/abcd_blues_small.php
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2016:16:46:33 --0500] [dart/sid#7fb5728385b8][rid#7fb572a796a0/initial] (1) [perdir /Users/santa/Sites/www.dartpro.com/] escaping http://dart/scrpts/abcd_blues_small.php for redirect
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Oct/2016:16:46:33 --0500] [dart/sid#7fb5728385b8][rid#7fb572a796a0/initial] (1) [perdir /Users/santa/Sites/www.dartpro.com/] redirect to http://dart/scrpts/abcd_blues_small.php [REDIRECT/302]
```

Can someone please help me get these different patterns going to the different substitutions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try with :

```
RewriteRule ^/?(?:products|Main)/abcd_?blue_?small.*$ /scrpts/abcd_blues_small.php      [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?(?:products|Main)/abcd_?red_?big.*$ /scrpts/abcd_red.big.php      [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?(?:products|Main)/abcd_?green.*$ /scrpts/abcd_green.php      [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^/?(?:products|Main)/abcd_?yellow_?large.*$ /scrpts/abcd_yellow.php      [NC,R,L]
```

Because now you test with the first rule:
`^/?products`
or
`Main/abcd_?blue_?small.*$`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work perfectly with all of my tests! But I don't understand at all why the change makes it work - using in the pattern (?:products|Main) instead of just "products|Main" Can you explain easily?

Thank you very much